# Mongodb output field with multiple $cond

Tags: mongodb

Here's an example of documents I use :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("554a1f5fe36a768b362ea5c0"),
    "store_state" : 1,
    "services" : [
        {
            "id" : "XXX",
            "state" : 1,
            "active": true
        },
        {
            "id" : "YYY",
            "state" : 1,
            "active": true
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I want to output a new field with "Y" if the id is "XXX" and active is true and "N" in any other cases. The service element with "XXX" as id is not present on every documents (output "N" in this case).

Here's my query for the moment :

```
db.stores.aggregate({ 
    $match : {"store_state":1}
},
{ $project : { 
    "XXX_active": { 
        $cond: [ {
            $and:[
                {$eq:["services.$id","XXX"]},
                {$eq:["services.$active",true]}
            ]},"Y","N"
        ] }
    }
}).pretty()
```

But it always output `"N"` for `"XXX_active"` field.

The expected output I need is :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("554a1f5de36a768b362e7e6f"), 
    "XXX_active" : "Y" 
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("554a1f5ee36a768b362e9d25"), 
    "XXX_active" : "N" 
}, 
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("554a1f5de36a768b362e73a5"), 
    "XXX_active" : "Y" 
}
```

Other example of possible result :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("554a1f5de36a768b362e7e6f"), 
    "XXX_active" : "Y",
    "YYY_active" : "N"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("554a1f5ee36a768b362e9d25"), 
    "XXX_active" : "N",
    "YYY_active" : "N"
}, 
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("554a1f5de36a768b362e73a5"), 
    "XXX_active" : "Y",
    "YYY_active" : "Y"
}
```

Only one `XXX_active` per object and no duplicates objects but I need all objects with an `XXX_active` even if the services id element "XXX" is not present. Could someone help please?

Comment: Can you show us the expected output?

Comment: The output I needed is : 

{ "_id" : ObjectId("554a1f5de36a768b362e7e6f"), "XXX_active" : "Y" } { "_id" : ObjectId("554a1f5ee36a768b362e9d25"), "XXX_active" : "N" } { "_id" : ObjectId("554a1f5de36a768b362e73a5"), "XXX_active" : "Y" } 

Only one XXX_active per object. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `services` array and then used `$cond` as below :

```
db.stores.aggregate({
    "$match": {
        "store_state": 1
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$services"
}, {
    "$project": {
        "XXX_active": {
            "$cond": [{
                "$and": [{
                    "$eq": ["$services.id", "XXX"]
                }, {
                    "$eq": ["$services.active", true]
                }]
            }, "Y", "N"]
        }
    }
},{"$group":{"_id":"$_id","XXX_active":{"$first":"$XXX_active"}}}) //group by id
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it works but not exactly the way I wanted.

Does I need to group if I want only one result "XXX_active" with Y or N (because there is always one service XXX) ?

With your solution, the query will check XXX / true on every services and output a result for every services right ?

The output I needed is :

{ "_id" : ObjectId("554a1f5de36a768b362e7e6f"), "XXX_active" : "Y" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("554a1f5ee36a768b362e9d25"), "XXX_active" : "N" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("554a1f5de36a768b362e73a5"), "XXX_active" : "Y" }

Only one XXX_active per object.

Thanks,

Comment: thanks, if I look at the $group you take the first XXX_active but the service XXX is not always in the first position in services array, with this solution we could take the XXX_Active check for the YYY service right ?

Comment: I'll test with $match, $unwind and $match before the $project to suppress some array elements.

Answer (score 0):

The following aggregation pipeline will give the desired result. You would need to first apply the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator on the `services` array field first as your initial aggregation pipeline step. This will deconstruct the `services` array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document replaces the array with an element value.

```
db.stores.aggregate([
    {
        "$match" : {"store_state": 1}
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$services"
    },
    {
        "$project": { 
            "store_state" : 1,
            "services": 1,
            "XXX_active": { 
                "$cond": [ 
                    {
                        "$and": [
                            {"$eq":["$services.id", "XXX"]},
                            {"$eq":["$services.active",true]}
                        ]
                    },"Y","N"
                ] 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "services.id": "XXX"
        }
    }, 
    {
       "$group": {
           "_id": {
               "_id": "$_id",
               "store_state": "$store_state",
               "XXX_active": "$XXX_active"
           },
           "services": {
               "$push": "$services"
           }
       }
   },
   {
       "$project": {
           "_id": "$_id._id",
            "store_state" : "$_id.store_state",
            "services": 1,
            "XXX_active": "$_id.XXX_active"
       }
   }   
])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! It slow down the query but the result is OK.

Comment: Consider adding an index on the `store_state` field but firstly to confirm whether `find({"store_state": 1})` is using the index, presumably `"store_state_1"`, could you post the `.explain()`?  Otherwise, your aggregation pipeline should use the same query plan as the `find()`.

Comment: I just saw that your solution is not exactly good.

It outputs same ID twice, one with "Y" at XXX_active if XXX is present and active. But another same ID with "N" for the other services.

Comment: Is it not possible to output the field XXX_active only in the array element with "XXX" as services.id ? And do the same for YYY per example. The XXX element will have an XXX_active field for output and the YYY element will have an YYY_active field for output ??

Comment: Thanks but your update will output XXX_active only if service element with id "XXX" is present in the document. I need the XXX_active field for every documents event if the "XXX" element is not present on services (however "services" array is always present).I'm sorry I may have not correctly write my problem. I've just updated my first post.